# How to enable international (roaming) data, but disable international calls?`

Tags: calls, mobile-data, roaming

While android has some settings as far as disabling roaming completely, I would simply like to disable only calls (due to their expensive nature), and allow MMS/data via roaming - is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can block the calls, but I dont know if there's a way to disable them.

Avast has one such built in tool to block calls by pattern i.e. wildcard characters.
e.g. block all calls with +1800* ( i.e. block all calls starting with +1800)

Comment: Does it have a way to disable them only while roaming?

Comment: You can disable/enable call blocking when in roaming...but that's manually.